# C# DataGridView Delete Key and Backspace Key

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in C# winform, which there is one `DataGridViewNumericCell`.
When I double click the cell to edit, any `Delete` key or `Backspace` key pressed will modify the value, but after I press `Enter` or navigate away from the cell, the value revert back to the original value.

Anyone know why and how can I make the value stay without reverting back to the original value?

Comment: You should share code snippets for us to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

All the thing you should do is to save the change to your datasource/database.